# Height for controls look different on iOS and Android with Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am attempting to unify my UI controls across the platforms. When using the same height request for iOS and Android, the controls' height are slightly different. Is there a way to unify these heights without using the OnPlatform method through XAML?

Android:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzgcW.png

iOS:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9F7BG.png

In the pictures it looks relatively the same (Height of 56). It looks the same only when OnPlatform Android is changed to ~65. Is there an alternative to this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvkmD.png

```
<OnPlatform x:Key="EntryHeight" x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
    <On Platform="iOS" Value="56" />
    <On Platform="Android" Value="56" />
</OnPlatform>
```

Comment: Hi , have you solved it ?  if answer be helpful , remember to mark that when you have time :-)

Comment: No, not yet :-(

Comment: Okey , if used `HeightRequest` to set height for `Entry` , I will see they own the same height .

Answer (score -2):

The entries look about the same size, but Android adds weird spacing around its entries. you need to write a custom renderer and set `Control.SetPadding(0,0,0,0)`. That'll remove that empty space between "Entry" and your actual entry control.

Comment: My iOS is actually the one that looks smaller

Comment: yeah i misinterpreted the question and thought you might be referring to the extra whitespace that android adds around entries. You're already using OnPlatform. why not just set android a bit smaller or iOS a bit larger to account for the difference?

Comment: The onPlatform works, but it takes a lot of eyeballing. I wanted to know if there was an ideal alternative to unite both heights (rather than guessing and trying best to make them as close together as possible). I am hoping that this alternative would make things easier between the UX design and development.

Comment: you can set the general theme for entries in ```App.xaml.cs```. That will allow you to set it to different values for each platform, but only in one place. Once you figure out the values you want to set, you shouldn't have to change it again.

`<Style TargetType="Entry">
 <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="{StaticResource EntryHeight}"/>
</Style>`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but yes, this is how I currently have it. The "themes" are set in a constants file along with other properties. I'll probably have to stick with this if I cannot find an alternative.